# listings package: last whitespace removed before the newline character. How to keep it?

Tags: listings, bash, lstdefinestyle

I've some sort of template/examples of bash scripts on my computer (.sh files on my hd) in which I put commands and commented outputs. This is my example.sh file:

```
echo     this    is    wide    spaced    
#this is wide spaced
echo     this    is    $'\n'    wide    spaced    
#this is <-notice the whitespace here before the newline
# wide spaced
```

(I've added "<-notice the whitespace here before the newline" not present in my script). From time to time I compile them in latex to add more information, importing them with lstinputlisting. I've defined:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\lstdefinestyle{customBashStyle}{
  keepspaces=true,
  language=Bash,
  showspaces=true,
}

\lstinputlisting[style=customBashStyle]{./example.sh}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that it preserves all the spaces making them visible, except for the whitespace before the newline character. How can I make that whitespace present and visible as well?

Answer (score 3):

This has to do with the very low level process with which TeX reads from files, which happens in a few steps; the most relevant for the problem at hand is, quoting the TeXbook, page 46,

> TeX deletes any ⟨space⟩ characters (number 32) that occur at the right end of an input line.

Most implementation of TeX also delete tab characters (number 9). This happens even before the tokenization process starts transforming characters into tokens, so the trailing space is gone for good when `listings` does its job for a given line.

For the special case when showing a trailing space is needed, which should be rare as shell scripts work the same as TeX and ignore trailing spaces, you can use the `escapechar` feature:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\lstdefinestyle{customBashStyle}{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  columns=fullflexible,
  keepspaces=true,
  language=Bash,
  showspaces=true,
}

%\lstinputlisting[style=customBashStyle]{./example.sh}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=customBashStyle,escapechar=\%]
echo     this    is    wide    spaced
#this is wide spaced
echo     this    is    $'\n'    wide    spaced
#this is %%
# wide spaced
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm afraid there's no other way for getting a printed trailing space. As escape character you can use any that doesn't appear in the code to be printed.

Comment: Thanks, this works. The drawback is that I have to edit my sh files to add that trailing character. Besides it's quite difficult to find an available character to use as an escapechar, unless I use something exotic like `¼`. I have 2 questions: 1) is there a way to use a combination of character as `escapechar`? 2) Can I achive the same result if I `deletecomment=[l]\#` and then I escape to latex everything after `escapechar=\#`, using a `basicstyle` for listings equal to the default `commentstyle`?

Comment: @the_eraser 1) I think it's possible: look in the manual for `escapeinside` 2) I don't understand, sorry

Comment: 1) ok I've used `escapeinside={(*@}{@*)}` 2) yeah, I've twisted the point :D ... the point is not escaping to latex at all, but adding an "invisible" extra character as a trailing character.

Comment: @the_eraser If you add an invisible character, you'll be in trouble when editing: how do you know it's there? `;-)`

Comment: Maybe it's crazy but I was trying another solution building up from `literate={\^^M}{}1`, which removes all the end of line characters (`\^^M`). This is not enough of course. I was thinking of doing something like `literate={\^^M\#}{{\space}{\^^M}{\#}}3`, but it gives me errors.

Comment: With `literate={\^^M}{\space}{1\newline}` I managed to remove all the end of line characters replacing each of them with a space followed by a newline character. Now the trailing space is present but it's the only one not visible. Other side effects are that everything after the first `#` becomes a comment (broken into lines or not) and the indentation is messed up. I give up trying other solutions than @egreg one, but I provided this info in case someone is interested.